# Script to extract zip files in seperate folders to their own folders

Tags: zip, unzip

I have hundreds of folders each containing a zip file. I would like to extract each zip file to where they are located. Is there a simple trick or script to do this?

EDIT:

Each folder is under the same parent folder. So the hierarchy is as the following:

```
PARENT FOLDER
-SubFolder1
--somefile.zip
-Subfolder2
--somefile.zip
...
-SubfolderN
--somefile.zip
```

Comment: Please be more specific, e.g. it's important to know which OS you're using.

Comment: I have access to both a linux and windows machine so an answer to do it for any of them is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under unix you could use something like

`find <dir> -iname '*.zip' -execdir unzip {} \;`

The program find traverses `<dir>` recursively and on every .zip file it finds it will change to that files directory and executes unzip on it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows version:

```
for /r "C:\Some\Directory" %f in (*.zip) do unzip "%f" -d "%~dpf"
```

*Warning: Completely untested.*

References:

- http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx
- http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html

I think with 7-zip it would be

```
for /r "C:\Some\Directory" %f in (*.zip) do 7z x -o "%~dpf" "%f"
```

but that's even untesteder.

Comment: thanks @melpomene but unzip is not recognized. here is the output: "'unzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Yes, this command assumes you have `unzip` installed, of course. (Apparently I got mine with [texlive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/). Interesting!)