# Batch: Extracting each zip in folder x, to a seperate folder

Tags: batch-file, powershell, zip

'Ello,

Using Batch (or Powershell or something), I want to do the following:
From folder x, I want to extract all .zip files to their own folder.

Example:

```
[Folder x]
- a.zip
- b.zip
- c.zip
```

**Into:**

```
[Folder x]
- [a]
- [b]
- [c]
- a.zip
- b.zip
- c.zip
```

I got until the point that I can extract every zip using the following batch:

```
for /r %%f in (*.zip) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%f" -o"%%~dpf"
```

But that resulted in that all contents were extracted to the root folder rather than to a new folder for each zip.
I used [Script to extract zip files in seperate folders to their own folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895624/script-to-extract-zip-files-in-seperate-folders-to-their-own-folders) as basis for the batch line above.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: This is a PowerShell example, which differs significantly from your batch script. Just an FYI.

Assume that you have some ZIP files in the `c:\test` folder. The following script will:

- Get a list of ZIP files in `c:\test`
- For each ZIP file ...

  - Create a folder based on the ZIP file's "base name" (file name sans extension)
  - Build the command line arguments to extract the ZIP file
  - Extract the ZIP file

To make this code work for you, you will need to update:

- The path to the ZIP file(s)
- The path to `7za.exe`

  - If `7za.exe` is contained in the `PATH` environment variable, then you do not need to specify the full path to the executable. I simply did it for clarity.

Script:

```
$ZipFileList = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test\*.zip;

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFileList) {
    mkdir -Path ('{0}\{1}' -f $ZipFile.Directory, $ZipFile.BaseName);
    $ArgumentList = 'x "{0}" -o"{1}\{2}\"' -f $ZipFile.FullName, $ZipFile.Directory, $ZipFile.BaseName;
    Start-Process -FilePath c:\windows\7za.exe -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of the differences - I just need a simple script to be executed on W2k8 server, without any extra installs (we deliver it with 7z included :] )
Works like a charm!
Only thing is; that I could not find any 7za.exe. So I changed ti to 7z.exe; which works as well ;-p

Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear it! 7za.exe is the command line version, but I guess 7z.exe works also :) Cheers mate.